# Mapping JSON Attribute to custom C# class

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I am trying to map a JSON response to a c# class using RestSharp. I am able to correctly map almost all the fields from the response, however there are a few, namely the attribute fields, that are being marked as `null`. I am wondering if there is something special I need to do in order to handle these cases.

The return of the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Response": {
      "@VersionNumber": "5.0",
      "ResponseDetail": {
           "CriteriaText": {
               "$": "Name"
               }
       }
       "ResultQuantity": 1,
       "Result": [
               {
                 "Id": "1234567890",
                 "PrimaryName": {
                 "OrganizationName": {
                     "$": "CompanyName"
                     }
                 }
               }
      }
}
```

I am able to pull in all the data correctly, except anything that is an attribute (starts with @ or $).

Here is how I am trying to map the response:

```
public class Response
{
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public ResponseDetail ResponseDetail { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to add this above the VersionNumber `[JsonProperty("@VersionNumber")]`, however that was unsuccessful as well.

Here is my GET call:

```
public Response GetData(string endpoint)
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
                Resource = _version + endpoint,
                RootElement = "Response"
            };
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", _token);

            var response = _client.Execute<Response>(request);

            if (response == null || !PassCodes.Contains(response.StatusCode))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return response.Data;
        }
```

Any thoughts would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I was looking for by doing a simple string replace. I stripped out any leading @ as well as renamed any single "$" to Value.

```
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = (x =>
        {
            x.Content = x.Content.Replace("\"@", "\"").Replace("\"$\"","\"Value\"");
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty` attribute, you need to switch RestSharp from its own serializer to Newtonsoft.Json. Look at this code as a basis: http://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/.

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonSerializer : IJsonSerializer
{
    private Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer;

    public NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        this.serializer = serializer;           
    }

    public string ContentType {
        get { return "application/json"; } // Probably used for Serialization?
        set { }
    }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public string RootElement { get; set; }

    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);

                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(RestSharp.IRestResponse response)
    {
        var content = response.Content;

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(content))
        {
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
            }
        }
    }

    public static NewtonsoftJsonSerializer Default
    {
        get
        {
            return new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

If latest RestSharp version is used, you need to add a parameterless ctor:

```
public NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()
{
    this.serializer = new JsonSerializer();
}
```

and register `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer` as:

```
client.AddHandler("application/json", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
```

And then `JsonProperty` will work:

```
[JsonProperty("@Foo")]
public string Foo { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("$")]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```

Comment: That is helpful to know.. I can give this a shot. Is there a better approach to my question or is this probably the best bet?

Comment: @KevinMee,  it's recommended (and probably the only one) way to customize serialization (as described in readme: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/readme.txt). And it is flexible: any JSON framework may be used, not only Json.NET.

Comment: thank you for your response.. I am working on implementing this however it seems during my testing that now I am not getting the data from the response (it still exists in the Content part).. am I missing something?

Comment: @KevinMee, I'm not sure these two serializers are fully compartible so it is better to start from simple case and deserialize simple json response like `{ "Normal": "OK" }` and then add complicated properties one by one.